# Match interface with local storage item

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have an interface :

```
export interface Me {
  id: number;
  email: string;
}
```

I have my component :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   me: Me;  
   ngOnInit() {
       this.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('me'));
       console.log(this.me);
   }
}
```

And in console I have :

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "lastname": "lastname",
  "firstname": "firstname",
  "email": "@mail.ru",
  "enable": true
}
```

Normally I should have only the fields : `id, email`. But I get the whole response from `/me` api call. Have you an idea how I can cast the interface to the reponse from localStorage ? Thx in advance.

Comment: @SGalea thank you, I want to do like this because I'm thinking that will be a clean way to get properties using Me interface...so no solution in this case ?

Comment: Typescript is only there to catch errors at compilation time. It doesn't do anything extra than JavaScript. Interfaces compile to nothing. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWTwG8AoORAEwC44kBXAWwCM0BuMuYBzBAGxoDOMKMgDm7AL5A

Comment: You can defined a property or variable of type `Me`, and then instantiate it with the values from local storage? The very same way you would do it in JavaScript